# Will yellow markings on passport affect my US visa application?

Tags: passports, us-visa, damaged-passports

My passport has this yellow markings on the corner of first and last pages. I have a US visa appointment scheduled. Will this be considered damaged.

Comment: We cannot see what you see. Take a picture, or several, of the passport pages with yellow marks, then obscure your personal data (name, photo, passport number, etc.) on the picture(s) you've taken, and attach into your question using the "Edit" button below the question text, then select the "Moon & Mountains" button above the text entry box.

Comment: Which country issued the passport?

Answer (score 2):

In broad strokes since even a photo would not necessarily help...

If the laminated personal data has any markings then very likely you need to get a new passport, it does not easily get marked since it's laminated and it's full of security features, many invisible to the naked eye and it's hard to tell without an UV light and magnifying glasses whether something important got covered. Even with those, you do not quite know what even to look for. So: get a new passport if the laminated page is disfigured.

For other pages, small markings are not too important, especially on visa pages which are expected to be covered up with visas anyways. Of course, if you poured a tub of yellow paint over one of the pages then that passport is done for -- you can use common sense here, I believe.